# Access State / Property and make it accessible throughout the solution

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react node js Project. In one controller I have an authentication mechanism that returns me a token, which I am using to make other APIs. Each API is triggered from a button click that itself is wrapped in separate react controllers.

I am currently storing token in KV and then all other functions are reading the value from Kv.

Can someone guide me the right way to setup architecture where I can get a token and reuse it everywhere within the same solution without storing it anywhere but reusing same context.?

I am not looking for a complete solution, but any pointers in design pattern will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can store the token in your local storage. And access from anywhere in the project.
When you logout, clear the token from local storage